# Hash values not updating in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I have a hash I declare in my header section globally:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require(["dijit/form/Form", "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/domReady!", "dijit/layout/TabContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/form/Select", "dojo/domReady", "dijit/TitlePane", "dijit/form/Textarea", "dojo", "dojox/xml/parser", "dijit/form/ValidationTextB

var dataHash = {};
```

I then interact with it, and put values in over a for loop.  However, when the last for loop exits, the hash still has the original contents:

```
for (key in dataHash) {
    for (key2 in dataHash[key]) {
        match = null;
        contentStr = dataHash[key][key2];

        if ( contentStr.match(selEx) ) {

            if ( contentStr.match(rEx) ) {
                var test = contentStr.replace(rEx, replaceStr.value);
                /* here, i change the value at the location dataHash[key][key2] */
                dataHash[key][key2] = test;
                console.log(dataHash[key][key2]);
            }

        } else if ( selValStr == "all" ) {

            if ( contentStr.match(rEx) ) {
                 var test = contentStr.replace(rEx, replaceStr.value);
                 dataHash[key][key2] = test;
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(dataHash)); /* Here, it prints the original content, and not the updated content */
```

Comment: Can you produce a fully executable example? This looks very weird so I'm betting it must be some silly mistake somewhere...

Comment: second that, from looks of the above - the dataHash will get updated. its just me being dj maniac but, `dojo.forEach(dataHash, function(value, key) { dojo.forEach(value, function(str, key2) { dataHash[key][key2] = str.replace(..); }); });` looks nicer =)